# LINQ to Entities: Loading One-To-Many Navigation Properties in Strong Typed Projections

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Here the relevant part of my model:

[image]

And here the code from my model class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a list of vans for binding with the BeachReach Snapshot
/// grid. Note: This method uses a POCO class that does not participate
/// in management by the entity context. See the DisplayVan class for more info
/// </summary>
/// <param name="setVanIDs">
/// You may limit which vans will be returned by passing a hash
/// set of their van IDs here
/// </param>
/// <returns>List of type DisplayVan - Unmanaged</returns>
public static List<DisplayVan> GetVansForSnapshot(HashSet<int> setVanIDs = null) {

    using (BeachReachDataEntities objContext = new BeachReachDataEntities()) {

        var qryVans = from v in objContext.vans
                                .Include("school")
                                .Include("location")

                      select new DisplayVan {
                          vanID = v.vanID,
                          vanName = v.vanName,
                          phone = v.phone,
                          capacity = (int)v.capacity,
                          schoolName = v.school.schoolName,
                          lastLocationName = v.location.locationName,
                          statusNote = v.statusNote,
                          isOffline = (v.isOffline == 1) ? true : false,
                          isPrayerRoom = (v.isPrayerRoom == 1) ? true : false,
                          isNotReady = (v.isNotReady == 1) ? true : false,
                          creationDate = v.creationDate,
                          modifiedDate = v.modifiedDate,
                          vanAssignments = (from va in objContext.vanAssignments
                                            from pr in objContext.pickupRequests
                                            where va.vanID == v.vanID
                                            where pr.pickupRequestID == va.pickupRequestID
                                            select va)
                      };

        if (setVanIDs != null && setVanIDs.Count > 0)
            return qryVans.Where(v => setVanIDs.Contains(v.vanID)).ToList<DisplayVan>();
        else
            return qryVans.ToList<DisplayVan>();

    }

}

// --------------------------------------------------------
```

I have also tried:

```
        var qryVans = from v in objContext.vans
                                .Include("school")
                                .Include("location")
                                .Include("vanAssignments")
                                .Include("vanAssignments.pickupRequest")


                      select new DisplayVan {
                          vanID = v.vanID,
                          vanName = v.vanName,
                          phone = v.phone,
                          capacity = (int)v.capacity,
                          schoolName = v.school.schoolName,
                          lastLocationName = v.location.locationName,
                          statusNote = v.statusNote,
                          isOffline = (v.isOffline == 1) ? true : false,
                          isPrayerRoom = (v.isPrayerRoom == 1) ? true : false,
                          isNotReady = (v.isNotReady == 1) ? true : false,
                          creationDate = v.creationDate,
                          modifiedDate = v.modifiedDate,
                          vanAssignments = v.vanAssignments
                      };
```

Ignore the is**** properties. I'm using a MySQL database which doesn't support `boolean` types.

The query must project onto `DisplayVan` instead of the `van` entity because I have some computed properties that I'm binding to the datagrid.

The problem is when I try to access the `pickupRequest` navigation property of the `vanAssignment` entity. No matter what I do, the `pickupRequest` property is `null`. Note, I do have lazy loading off. How can I load the vanAssignment's pickupRequest relation via my query above?

One last note: the `vanAssignments` property is a List of type `vanAssignment`. Thanks for any insight you can lend to this issue.

**Edit**

One additional question. So taking from your example, I wanted to go to vanAssignment.person.firstName. I tried this:

```
        var qryVans = (from v in objContext.vans
                       select new {
                           DisplayVan = new DisplayVan {
                               vanID = v.vanID,
                               vanName = v.vanName,
                               phone = v.phone,
                               capacity = (int)v.capacity,
                               schoolName = v.school.schoolName,
                               lastLocationName = v.location.locationName,
                               statusNote = v.statusNote,
                               isOffline = (v.isOffline == 1) ? true : false,
                               isPrayerRoom = (v.isPrayerRoom == 1) ? true : false,
                               isNotReady = (v.isNotReady == 1) ? true : false,
                               creationDate = v.creationDate,
                               modifiedDate = v.modifiedDate,
                               vanAssignments = v.vanAssignments
                           },
                           PickupRequests = v.vanAssignments.Select(va => va.pickupRequest),
                           People = v.vanAssignments.Select(va => va.pickupRequest.person)
                       }).ToList().Select(e => e.DisplayVan);
```

When I try to access that property, I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var qryVans = 
    (from v in objContext.vans
    select new
        {
            DisplayVan = new DisplayVan
            {
                vanID = v.vanID,
                vanName = v.vanName,
                phone = v.phone,
                capacity = (int)v.capacity,
                schoolName = v.school.schoolName,
                lastLocationName = v.location.locationName,
                statusNote = v.statusNote,
                isOffline = (v.isOffline == 1) ? true : false,
                isPrayerRoom = (v.isPrayerRoom == 1) ? true : false,
                isNotReady = (v.isNotReady == 1) ? true : false,
                creationDate = v.creationDate,
                modifiedDate = v.modifiedDate,
                vanAssignments = v.vanAssignments
            },
            PickupRequests = v.vanAssignments.Select(va => new {PickupReuqest = va.pickupRequest, Person = va.pickupRequest.Person})
        }
    ).ToList().Select(e => e.DisplayVan);
```

Includes are ignored in this construction, so you should leave them. You should specify with additional property, that you want pickupRequests too. `ToList()` executes query taking demanded data and since all required pickupRequests are in context, you will have correct fields populated. EF analyzes fields, that you requests in your view model and prepares sql statement, that will take them.

Comment: Amazingly, that did work. However, I don't quite understand it. Could you walk me through it?

Comment: @Jesse Bunch: Comment added. Do you need more?

Comment: What is throwing me off is that you're projecting onto an anonymous type with two properties: DisplayVan and PickupRequests yet somehow it comes out as a type of DisplayVan with DisplayVan.VanAssignments.PickupRequest being filled correctly. So I'm not sure how it gets from Anonymous Type to DisplayVan?

Comment: @Jesse Bunch: All these entities are stored in ObjectContext. Since ObjectContext sees that PickupRequest objects have foreign key values related to VanAssignment objects in the same context VanAssignment.PickupRequests collection is properly populated. Yeah, I like that too:) You can even run different queries in the same context and if data is somehow related, navigation properties will work.

Comment: @LukLed Okay, thank you for checking this out. Could you take a look at my edit above? I am trying to take your example a step further and am receiving an InvalidCastException. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jesse Bunch: I made an edit, maybe try with it. I am not sure about reson of this error.

Comment: You're a life saver. That worked very well. I think I can tinker with this to figure out the rest. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: @Jesse Bunch: EF had probably some kind of problem with translating your query to SQL, but it looked valid.